# apply listener to only new items with ajax infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using [ajax infinite scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html) to load content on my website, and I have a listener event for each item that shows a new element with additional information.

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></div>
  <div class="item"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="pagination">
  <a href="?page=2" class="next">Next</a>
</div>

var ias = jQuery.ias({
      container:  '.items',
      item:       '.item',
      pagination: '#pagination',
      next:       '.next'
});
```

And I'm using this to load the listener for each new page:

```
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
  var $items = $(items);

  $items.each(function() {
    $('.fa').click(function() {
      show($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });

});

function show(what) {
    $('body').append('<div class="options"></div>');
    $('.options').load('options.php?id='+id);
}
```

***My problem*** is that each time a new page loads, the listener gets applied to EVERY item, so when page 2 is loaded, items from page 1 will now append TWO .options and load it twice, and when page 3 is loaded, page 1 items load three times, and page 2 items load twice, etc. **How can I apply the listener to only the new page items when each new page loads?**

Comment: a quick try change `$('.fa')` with `$items.find('.fa')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unbind and rebind the event to only have one listener like so :

```
  $items.each(function() {
    $('.fa').unbind("click").click(function() {
      show($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });
```